# Why does angle deviation of a satellite not captured my Mars decreases as the Velocity of the satellite increases?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, satellites, escape-velocity

When a satellite is not captured by a planet, it is moving sufficiently fast. so why is it that the angle deviation of the satellite decreases as its initial velocity increases?

Comment: This question might fit better on http://space.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Multiple related reasons. There is *less time* to impart significant momentum $\int{F_\perp \,dt}$ in a transverse direction. Also, a given imparted transverse momentum is a *smaller fraction* of the initial momentum if you're going fast.